ImportError: For 8-bit quantization using bitsandbytes
quantization_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
    load_in_4bit=True,
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
    bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
    bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=True,
    bnb_4bit_quant_storage=torch.bfloat16,

)
llm = HuggingFaceLLM(
    model_name="meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf",
    tokenizer_name="meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf",
    query_wrapper_prompt=PromptTemplate("<|system|>\n\n<|user|>\n{query_str}\n<|assistant|>\n"),
    context_window=3900,
    max_new_tokens=256,
    model_kwargs={"quantization_config": quantization_config},
    # tokenizer_kwargs={},
    generate_kwargs={"temperature": 0.3, "top_k": 50, "top_p": 0.95},
    messages_to_prompt=messages_to_prompt,
    device_map="auto",

)

ERROR:
"Converting into 4-bit or 8-bit weights from tf/flax weights is currently not supported, please make " sure the weights are in PyTorch format."
I am facing the this issue. I have tried various methods but doesnt seem to work. The error says the weights are in tensorflow format but has to be changed to pytorch format to support loading 4 and 8 bits.
I have tried checking the version compatibility of python, transformers, hugging face and BitsAndBytes. ALL of these seem to be compatible enough to load the llama 2 LLM model but it still throws the error "Please, pass a BitsAndBytesConfig object in quantization_config argument instead".Kindly please help me by providing a solution to overcome this issue.
